# Problems after run: heroku run python manage.py migrate

Tags: python, django, heroku, migrate

While I was deployed my django app in heroku, I run:

```
  heroku run python3  manage.py migrate
```

and I get this messahe in my console:

```
  File "manage.py", line 16
  ) from exc
     ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

my manage.py file is actually:

```
  #!~/.virtualenvs/djangodev/bin/python
  """Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
  import os
  import sys


  def main():
      os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myApp3.settings')
      try:
          from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
      except ImportError as exc:
          raise ImportError(
              "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
              "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
              "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
          ) from exc
      execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

  if __name__ == '__main__':
      main()
```

When I run python => python3, the next message is displayed:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "manage.py", line 10, in main
      from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

  The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
      main()
    File "manage.py", line 16, in main
      ) from exc
  ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available       on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual       environment?
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a virtual enviorment first. Then install django in the virtual environment. You can do this through a thing called `pipenv`. you need to add this to your project by doing. `python install pipenv`. Then install python in that virtual enviorment by doing `pipenv install django`. when django installs you can then do your migrations.

Comment: Actually, I have my virtual enviroment first.